# how can I alphabetically sort an array of records where a record has a name: string field?

Tags: arrays, sorting, reason, bucklescript

```
let items = [| {name: "b"}, {name: "c"}, {name: "a"}|];
```

// expected output

```
[| {name: "a"}, {name: "b"}, {name: "c"}|];
```

Was thinking about using `Belt.SortArray.stableSortBy` but requires an `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`String.compare`](https://reasonml.github.io/api/String.html#VALcompare) happens to return an int, so you can just use that:

```js
let items = [| {name: "b"}, {name: "c"}, {name: "a"}|];

let sorted = Belt.SortArray.stableSortBy(items, (a, b) => String.compare(a.name, b.name));
```